# C#: How to programmatically compile a DLL with certain XML content in the resources of the DLL?

Tags: c#, windows, dll

More specifically, I'm wanting to compile the XML required by Microsoft to create a GDF.dll file, in order to add a game to the Games Explorer in Windows 7. I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655) KB article that explains how to programmatically compile source into a DLL or EXE, but I'm unsure how to properly compile a DLL that contains XML.

Answer (score 0):

I've never created or embedded GDF files before but after a quick search on msdn I believe you will need to do the following:

1. Use the [Game Definition File Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417676(v=VS.85).aspx) to create the GDF file and associated resource compiler scripts* (.rc files)
2. Compile the script with [RC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381055(v=VS.85).aspx)
3. Use the [CompilerParameters.Win32Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.win32resource.aspx) property to embed the .res file generated in step 2

*I'm making the assumption here that the Game Definition File Editor creates .rc files.  If the tool creates .resx files convert them to .resource files using the [resgen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1(v=VS.80).aspx) tool and embed them using the [CompilerParameters.EmbeddedResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.embeddedresources.aspx) property.

Comment: The thing is, I'm writing an application in which I'd like to be able to generate/compile these GDF files on the fly, rather than having to use a separate application (which would kind of negate a big part of the purpose I'm writing this application)